# Is "I just might have a chance" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if, "I just might have a chance" is grammatically correct. Consider the following sentence:

> "If you just knew what I feel for you, **I just might have a chance** to be with you."

Trying to stress that I might have a chance but just might not be sure of it.
I found [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-sounds-correct-I-might-just-compliment-you-or-I-just-might-compliment-you/answer/Bistappayya-Nadiger/) which says that this construction is wrong but I would like to get a second opinion.

Comment: Disassemble it.  "I have a chance."  Not sure?  "I might have a chance."  Really, really iffy?  "I just might have a chance."  "Just" modifies "might" while "might" modifies "have".  (The link you have isn't wrong, but it refers to a different scenario.)

Comment: 'Just' here is certainly not a central adverb. [Ekkehard König, in The Meaning of Focus Particles: A Comparative Perspective](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9NsgkWF-PY0C&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=focus+scalar+particle+just+only&source=bl&ots=HIdgwQexgn&sig=GYi6Y4rexfA_uz0lullNSZWeQDE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl_qTfqd_LAhWCbhQKHaEJBvUQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=focus%20scalar%20particle%20just%20only&f=false), classes it as a 'focus particle'....

Comment: These have complex distributions, being able to focus dramatic emphasis on the verb phrase (I just might have a chance = I might just have a chance), point out restriction in a verb phrase (I just looked; I didn't touch the buns), or point out restriction in a noun phrase say (Just John bought a pen / John bought just a pen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*, "just might" is fine. From the definition of "just":

> 5: perhaps
>   <It just might work.>
>   <It won't make it to retail shelves
>   for at least five years, if at all, but inexpensive rolls of plastic
>   coated with electricity-generating film just might. — Fred Guterl,
>   Newsweek, 23 Sept. 2002>

Comment: Thank you everyone for you answers they are very mind clearing. Thank you so much!